# ServiceStack: Custom CredentialsAuthProvider

Tags: authorization, servicestack

We need to pass extra info together with the Username and Password from a mobile client with Authentication. Is it possible to inherit from  CredentialsAuthProvider and define extra data members that can then be extracted by the server?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [Custom Authentication and Authorization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization) section of the wiki? You should be able to access any extra info you pass with the Username and Password doing something like...

```
public class MyAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        var extraInfo = authService.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().GetParam("extraInfo");

        //Add here your custom auth logic (database calls etc)
        //Return true if credentials are valid, otherwise false
    }
}
```